# How do I concatenate two matrices in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

How do I concatenate two matrices into one matrix? The resulting matrix should have the same height as the two input matrices, and its width will equal the sum of the width of the two input matrices.

I am looking for a pre-existing method that will perform the equivalent of this code:

```
def concatenate(mat0, mat1):
    # Assume that mat0 and mat1 have the same height
    res = cv.CreateMat(mat0.height, mat0.width + mat1.width, mat0.type)
    for x in xrange(res.height):
        for y in xrange(mat0.width):
            cv.Set2D(res, x, y, mat0[x, y])
        for y in xrange(mat1.width):
            cv.Set2D(res, x, y + mat0.width, mat1[x, y])
    return res
```

Comment: If you are working with matrices, you should be using `cv2`.  Its built-in support for `numpy` arrays makes these sort of questions one-liners.

Comment: You can also use `cv2.vconcat()` and `cv2.hconcat()`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579541/how-do-i-concatenate-two-matrices-in-python-opencv/72177160#72177160

Answer (score 13):

If you are using OpenCV, (you will get Numpy support then), you can use Numpy function `np.hstack((img1,img2))` to do this.

eg :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load two images of same size
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

both = np.hstack((img1,img2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use OpenCV. Legacy uses cvmat. But numpy arrays are really easy to work with.

As suggested by [@abid-rahman-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1134940/abid-rahman-k), you can use hstack(which I didn't know about) so I had used this.

```
h1, w1 = img.shape[:2]
h2, w2 = img1.shape[:2]
nWidth = w1+w2
nHeight = max(h1, h2)
hdif = (h1-h2)/2
newimg = np.zeros((nHeight, nWidth, 3), np.uint8)
newimg[hdif:hdif+h2, :w2] = img1
newimg[:h1, w2:w1+w2] = img
```

But if you want to work with Legacy code, this should help

Let's assume that height of img0 is greater than height of image

```
nW = img0.width+image.width
nH = img0.height
newCanvas = cv.CreateImage((nW,nH), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
cv.SetZero(newCanvas)
yc = (img0.height-image.height)/2
cv.SetImageROI(newCanvas,(0,yc,image.width,image.height))
cv.Copy(image, newCanvas)
cv.ResetImageROI(newCanvas)
cv.SetImageROI(newCanvas,(image.width,0,img0.width,img0.height))
cv.Copy(img0,newCanvas)
cv.ResetImageROI(newCanvas)
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has in-built functions for concatenating images vertically/horizontally:

- `cv2.vconcat()`
- `cv2.hconcat()`

***Note:*** While concatenating, images **must** be of the same dimensions or else you will come across an error message similar to: `error: (-215:Assertion failed)....`

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('flower.jpg', 1)

# concatenate images vertically    
vertical_concat = cv2.vconcat([img, img])
```

[image]

```
# concatenate images horizontally
horizontal_concat = cv2.hconcat([img, img])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled across it because I was looking to concatenate arrays that are two dimensions ( not just concatenate in 1 dimension ).

`np.hstack` will not do this.

Assuming you have two `640x480` images that are simply two dimensions use `dstack`.

```
a = cv2.imread('imgA.jpg')
b = cv2.imread('imgB.jpg')

a.shape            # prints (480,640)
b.shape            # prints (480,640)

imgBoth = np.dstack((a,b))
imgBoth.shape      # prints (480,640,2)

imgBothH = np.hstack((a,b))
imgBothH.shape     # prints (480,1280)  
                   # = not what I wanted, first dimension not preserverd
```

Comment: I think should be a new self-answered question, as this answer isn't related to original question