# How to concatenate three images?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (310,1643,3) (1673,1643,3)

```
add = (image1 + image2 + image3)

image1 = cv2.imread("OrchidAMHI0011570910_crop.jpg")
image2 = cv2.imread("OrchidAMHI0011570910_crop1.jpg")
image3 = cv2.imread("OrchidAMHI0011570910_crop2.jpg")
add = (image1 + image2 + image3)
cv2.imshow("Addition", add)
```

I expect the output as concatenation of all three images

Comment: You can use `cv2.vconcat()` and `cv2.hconcat()`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579541/how-do-i-concatenate-two-matrices-in-python-opencv/72177160#72177160

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you want a concatenation of your images as mentioned in the question body. This can be done, for example, by using OpenCV's [`hconcat`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4676b1376cdc4e528dab6bd9edc51c1a) and [`vconcat`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga558e169e15adcc46b8cdcc6cd215070f) functions.

Here's a short example for a vertical concatenation. Please pay attention, that the width has to be the same for all input images. For horizontal concatenation, the height has to be the same.

Let's have these three input images:

[image: Input 1]

[image: Input 2]

[image: Input 3]

Then, we use this short code snippet:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up sample images for vertical concatenation; width must be identical
image1 =  64 * np.ones((100, 200, 3), np.uint8)
image2 = 128 * np.ones((200, 200, 3), np.uint8)
image3 = 192 * np.ones((300, 200, 3), np.uint8)

# Concatenate using cv2.vconcat
add = cv2.vconcat([image1, image2, image3])

# Visualization
cv2.imshow('image1', image1)
cv2.imshow('image2', image2)
cv2.imshow('image3', image3)
cv2.imshow('Addition', add)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And, the final result looks like this:

[image: Output]

Another option could be, since OpenCV uses NumPy under the hood, to use [`vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html). So, instead of

```py
add = cv2.vconcat([image1, image2, image3])
```

you could also use

```py
add = np.vstack([image1, image2, image3])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: # Set up sample images for vertical concatenation; width must be identical
               image1 =  64 * np.ones(('OrchidAMHI0011570910_crop.jpg'), np.uint8)
               image2 = 128 * np.ones(('OrchidAMHI0011570910_crop1.jpg'),np.uint8)
               image3 = 192 * np.ones(('OrchidAMHI0011570910_crop2.jpg'),np.uint8) 
 TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @BIBINVARKEY No, you just leave your initial `image1 = cv2.imread("OrchidAMHI0011570910_crop.jpg")`, etc. The `np.ones(...)` stuff was just to set up sample images. Please have a look at some basic tutorials on Python and OpenCV before continuing to work on "bigger" problems.

Comment: @HansHire: I understand that the above was just an example. However, I have cropped an image into 3 part and done skew correction on all 3 parts and then concatenated all 3 cropped parts together. However, the middle portion of the image which I deskewed after cropping remains the same after concatenation.   But I have done concatenation of all three now