# Combining two images horizontally in python using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, file, opencv, concatenation

I have four images, each slices of a larger image. If I string them together horizontally, then I get the larger image. To complete this task, I'm using python 2.7 and the OpenCV library, specifically the hconcat() function. Here is the code:

```
with open("tempfds.jpg", 'ab+') as f:
            f.write(cv2.hconcat(cv2.hconcat(cv2.imread("491411.jpg"),cv2.imread("491412.jpg")),cv2.hconcat(cv2.imread("491413.jpg"),cv2.imread("491414.jpg"))))
```

When I run it, everything works fine. But when I try to open the image itself, I get an error: `Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x86 0x7e)`. All the images I'm using are jpg's, so I don't understand why this error is occurring. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: The error message is correct. JPEGs start with `0xff` `0xd8`.

Comment: You can also use `cv2.vconcat()` and `cv2.hconcat()`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579541/how-do-i-concatenate-two-matrices-in-python-opencv/72177160#72177160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a JPEG, you need:

```
cv2.imwrite('lovely.jpg', image)
```

where `image` is all your images concatenated together.