# Combine two images using cv2.hconcat using python

Tags: python, opencv

**This is the code:**

```
for i in range(29):
  output_img=cv2.hconcat([image[i],Merged_images[i]])
  Output_images.append(output_img)
  i+=1
cv2_imshow(Output_images[0])
```

`image[] is a grayscale image and Merged_images[] is a merged image of x and y sobel processed images. code below`

```
for i in range(29):
  merg_img = cv2.addWeighted(FilterX[i],0.3,FilterY[i],0.3,0)
  Merged_images.append(merg_img)
  i+=1
cv2_imshow(Merged_images[6])
```

`When i try to horizontaly concat the two images this error is showing up. PLease help im new to python.`

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_operations.cpp:68: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].rows == src[0].rows && src[i].type() == src[0].type() in function 'hconcat'

Comment: Make sure both images have same dimensions

Comment: yes, or resize the second image to the dimensions of the first, then concatenate.

Comment: Pls check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579541/how-do-i-concatenate-two-matrices-in-python-opencv/72177160#72177160