# How to combine a RGB image with a Grayed image in opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv3.0, scikit-image

I refered this link to combine two images, and it works if both images are being RGB formated

[Combining Two Images with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589012/combining-two-images-with-opencv/24522170)

The question is how to combine a RGB image with a Grayed image, since the RGB image is three dimensions but gray image is two dimensions?

Comment: So, the result would be a 3D array with 4 columns?

Comment: Could you convert your grayscale image to a RGB one with imgcol=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) (the image will qtay visually gray but be structurally rgb) or is that what you're trying to avoid ?

Comment: @Divakar，3 columns

Comment: Your image array is already a 3D array with 3 columns. How could you add a gray image and still keep it 3 columns? Add a [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: @Divakar,I want to create a new image,the paste two images to this new image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RGB images are 3-dimensional whereas grayscale images are 2-dimensional. In order for the combination to be possible, you need to add one dimension to the grayscale image. If `x` is a 2-dimensional array `x`, the simplest way to transform it into a 3-dimensional array is `x[:, :, None]`. Alternatively, you could use NumPy's [`atleast_3D`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_3d.html).

The code below gets the job done using NumPy and scikit-image libraries:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

rgb = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6X5p.jpg')
gray = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/f27t5.png')

rows_rgb, cols_rgb, channels = rgb.shape
rows_gray, cols_gray = gray.shape

rows_comb = max(rows_rgb, rows_gray)
cols_comb = cols_rgb + cols_gray
comb = np.zeros(shape=(rows_comb, cols_comb, channels), dtype=np.uint8)

comb[:rows_rgb, :cols_rgb] = rgb
comb[:rows_gray, cols_rgb:] = gray[:, :, None]

io.imshow(comb)
```

[image: lions]

It is important to note that the example above assumes that both images are of type `np.uint8`. If not, you should use appropriate type conversions.