# Detect object in specific region of frame

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I would like to detect objects from the region of a frame using tensorflows object detection api. I have split the frame into region_1 and region_2 but how do I perform detection only in region_1 from the frame and draw rectangles only in region1

```
def detect_objects(image_np, sess, detection_graph):

    region_1 = image_np[zone1[1]: zone1[3], zone1[0]:zone1[2]]
    region_2 = image_np[zone2[1]: zone2[3], zone2[0]:zone2[2]]

    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

    scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

    (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
        [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=1)
    return image_np
```

Comment: Could you provide some background by sharing a link to TensorFlow's object detection API?

Answer (score 0):

You have to substitute the region you're interested in where image_np was before, so change

```
image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
```

to:

```
image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(region_1, axis=0)
```

and

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image_np,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=1)
return image_np
```

to:

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        region_1,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=1)
return region_1
```

If you want to return the original image with only boxes drawn on the region_1 side you'll have to either transform the box coordinates from region_1's dimensions back to the original image dimensions (which is hard given the different data types tf uses in their np.arrays) or [concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589012/combining-two-images-with-opencv) the regions back together:
To stack vertically (img1 over img2):

```
vis = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=0)
```

To stack horizontally (img1 to the left of img2):

```
vis = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
```