# show live stream and custom image in a window opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV and Python to show my webcam stream in realtime. Is there a way to show an image in the same window? I do not want to have two separate windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate those 2 images before they are displayed.

[This post shows how it's done.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7589012/176769)