# How to Concatenate 5 Images Out Of Multiple Images In a Folder

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, concatenation, python-imaging-library

I have a folder which has multiple images lets say images names are----

AB_1.jpg,
AB_2.jpg,
AB_3.jpg,
AB_4.jpg,
AB_5.jpg,
AB_6.jpg,
AB_7.jpg,
AB_8.jpg,
BC_1.jpg,
BC_2.jpg,
BC_3.jpg,
CA_1.jpg,
CA_2.jpg

Here my objective is to concatenate all the images till _5 or less than _5 as one image....

So basically what I am saying is that---
AB_1.jpg,
AB_2.jpg,
AB_3.jpg,
AB_4.jpg,
AB_5.jpg

will get concatenated vertically and file name lets say will be AB_Concat.jpg

_6,_7,_8 are skipped because we want to concatenate only images till _5 as one....

Similarly,,
BC_1.jpg,
BC_2.jpg,
BC_3.jpg

will get concatenated vertically and file name lets say will be BC_Concat.jpg as you can see here BC_3 is last one which is less than _5 so all will be concatenated vertically.....

So if anyone have any idea on how to achieve the same please help....

This question is not similar to the once where two images are concatenated since here we are concatenating images on the basis of value after underscore in a image....

This is something which I tried---

```py
import cv2

import shutil

import numpy as np   
        
import os   

from PIL import Image  
     
path = r"D:\split"

out = r"D:\concat_test"

os.makedirs(out,exist_ok=True)

imag_name =[]

imag_name1 = []

for img in os.listdir(path):

    folder  = img.rsplit("_",1)[0]  

    imag_name1.append((folder,img))

    images = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),0)

    imag_name.append((folder,images))

# to create a folder for multiple images contain same name  
   
for image,name in zip(imag_name,imag_name1):

    if image[0] == name[0]:

        folder_n = os.path.join(out,name[0])

        final_fldr = os.path.join(folder_n,name[1])

        os.makedirs(folder_n,exist_ok=True)

        cv2.imwrite(final_fldr,image[1])

# to concatinate the images

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(out):

    np_images = [cv2.imread(os.path.join(root,file),0) for file in files]

    np_name = list(set([file.rsplit("_",1)[0] for file in files]))
    

    if len(np_images) != 0:

        print(np_name)

        concat = cv2.vconcat(np_images)

        concatinated_images = os.path.join(out,"concatinated_images")

        os.makedirs(concatinated_images,exist_ok=True)

        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(concatinated_images,*np_name)+".tif",concat)

#to remove the unwanted folder

for remove_folder in os.listdir(out):

    if remove_folder != "concatinated_images":

        folders_to_remove = os.path.join(out,remove_folder)

        shutil.rmtree(folders_to_remove)
'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining Two Images with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589012/combining-two-images-with-opencv)

Comment: @InyoungKim No the above solution is not useful for me since it is bound for 2 images....

Since I have multiple images in a directory I want to combine all images with some filename till _5 only as one concatenated single images similarly for other images also....

Comment: Did any of these answers help solve your complex use case? If so, please [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  If not, please follow-up specifically so any outstanding concerns can be addressed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has lots of moving parts, so I will attempt to address all of them.  Hopefully the code helps with your use case.

The code below does this:

1. Determine what images exist in directory X
2. Group images based on file name
3. Create a temporary directory to store images based on group.  This directory will be removed automatically.
4. Copy local files to temporary directory
5. Chunk the files into blocks (5 files max)
6. Merge these chucks into a new image with a border separator

**Special Note**

During testing I noted that any list that did not contained the required 5 items would not format correctly. To fix this problem I created a blank_check.jpg, which allowed me to format the new image correctly.

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
import itertools
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps

def create_temp_directory(name):
    """
    This function create a temporary directory, which will
    be used to store files based on specific parts of a filename.
    :param name:
    :return:
    """
    temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(suffix=None, prefix=f'temp_directory_{name}', dir=None)
    return temp_dir


def divide_list_into_chunks(input_list, len_of_chunk):
    """
    This function will divide a list into chunks.
    :param input_list:
    :param len_of_chunk:
    :return:
    """
    for i in range(0, len(input_list), len_of_chunk):
       yield input_list[i:i + len_of_chunk]
 

def add_blank_checks(input_list, temp_dir):
    """
   :param input_list: 
   :param temp_dir: 
   :return: 
   """
   number_of_images = (5 - len(input_list))
   for _ in range(number_of_images):
      shutil.copy(f'blank_check.jpg', f'{temp_dir.name}/blank_check.jpg')
      input_list.append(f'{temp_dir.name}/blank_check.jpg')
   return input_list


def merge_images_vertically(list_of_images, file_name):
    """
    This function is designed to merge images vertically
    :param list_of_images: current list of images to process
    :param file_name: file name for the new image
    :return: 
    """
    # open images using Pillow
    images = [Image.open(im) for im in list_of_images]
    # Create separate lists to store the heights and widths
    # of the images
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
    width_of_new_image = min(widths)
    height_of_new_image = sum(heights)
    # create a new output image
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (width_of_new_image, height_of_new_image))
    new_pos = 0
    counter = 0
    for im in images:
       if counter == 0:
          new_im.paste(im, (0, new_pos))
          new_pos += im.size[1]
          counter += 1
       else:
          color = "black"
          border = (0, 10, 0, 0)
          img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(im, border=border, fill=color)
          new_im.paste(img_with_border, (0, new_pos))
          new_pos += im.size[1]
     new_im.save(f'{file_name}', "JPEG", quality=75, optimize=True, progressive=True)
     return


image_directory = "sample_images"
image_directory_abspath = os.path.abspath(image_directory)
images = os.listdir(image_directory_abspath)
accepted_extensions = ('.bmp', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.svg', '.tiff')
valid_image_extensions = [im for im in images if im.endswith(accepted_extensions)]
image_groups = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(valid_image_extensions), lambda x: x[0:2])]
for image_group in image_groups:
   count = 0
   name_group = image_group[0][:2]
   temp_directory = create_temp_directory(name_group)
   image_list = [shutil.copy(f'{image_directory_abspath}/{item}', f'{temp_directory.name}/{item}') for item in image_group]
   max_number_of_items = 5
   chunks = list(divide_list_into_chunks(image_list, max_number_of_items))
   for chunk in chunks:
      count += 1
      if len(chunk) == 5:
        merge_images_vertically(chunk, f'{name_group}_merged_{count}.jpeg')
      else:
        new_checks = add_blank_checks(chunk, temp_directory)
        merge_images_vertically(new_checks, f'{name_group}_merged_{count}.jpeg')
```

### Sample of merged image files

[image]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    macOS Catalina
Python:      3.8.0
Pillow:      8.0.1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

For iterating all files in the folder, use Python's [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.walk) method. For every file, use Python's [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the prefix and the number of the file. Do some checking regarding prefix changes and numbers above `5`, and just concatenate the images inside the loop. Since you concatenate only five images, doing that using vectorized approaches (e.g. via NumPy) will just give more unreadable code for a minor performance win.

Here's my full code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Iterate all files in folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("your/folder/somewhere/"):

    current_prefix = ''
    output = None

    for file in files:

        # Split filename
        splits = file.split('_')

        # Get prefix and number of filename
        prefix = splits[0]
        number = int(splits[1].split('.')[0])

        # If there's a prefix change...
        if prefix != current_prefix:

            # ... save last output image...
            if current_prefix != '' and output is not None:
                cv2.imwrite(root + current_prefix + '_Concat.jpg', output)

            # ... and set new prefix and initialize new output image
            current_prefix = prefix
            output = cv2.imread(root + file)

        # As long the current number is less or equal 5, concatenate
        elif number <= 5:
            output = np.concatenate([output, cv2.imread(root + file)], axis=0)

    # Save last output image separately
    cv2.imwrite(root + current_prefix + '_Concat.jpg', output)
```

I tested that code with a folder containing files `AB_1.jpg` ... `AB_8.jpg` and `BC_1.jpg` ... `BC_3.jpg`. As results I get `AB_Concat.jpg` with the first five images concatenated vertically, and `BC_Concat.jpg` with the existing three images.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
NumPy:       1.19.4
OpenCV:      4.4.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Getting Error--

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Comment: Error messages without context, in terms of a [mre], are useless. Set up a folder with a minimal example of valid images like I described in my answer and test my code again. I'm quite sure, that it'll work. Then, compare what's different between that minimal example and your actual folder with images. Most likely, not all images in your folder follow the proposed pattern.

Comment: The Images which I am testing are .tif images with following image details----

Horizontal resolution 200 dpi, Vertical resolution 200 dpi, Bit depth 1, Compression LZW, Resolution unit 2

Is above data effect anyhow your code....

Comment: I re-tested my code with some `tif` images, it still works. 1) Why do you ask for `jpg` images, if your actual setting uses `tif` images? 2) You still haven't provided a [mre]. Till you provide such, I won't further support here. Perhaps, one of your images cannot be read by `cv2.imread` and thus later concatenated. But again, without seeing a [mre] including some real images, no one here can help you.

Comment: I have added a code above which is working fine but the only issue which I am having is that I want to concatenate only images with _5 as one but with the above code lets say some images _10 variation it is concatinating all _10 images...

Comment: I had even attached images on which above code is not working.....

Comment: I just had a short look at your images. Most of them have different widths, such that vertical concatenating isn't possible without some padding for example. Nevertheless, that wouldn't explain the `ValueError` you mentioned. Since there's still no stack trace, showing the *exact error* in your *original code*, it's still impossible to help you.

Comment: Concerning Ani's error message.  I was able to recreate his issue by -- I created a dir with Ani's images.  I named the images as you suggested. When I ran your code I got this error:   output = np.concatenate([output, cv2.imread(root + file)], axis=0) File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

I had 10 minutes to write some code - explanation afterwards:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import glob, re
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Get list of filename prefixes by looking for "XX_1.jpg" images
prefixes = [ re.split('_', f)[0] for f in glob.glob('[A-Z][A-Z]_1.jpg') ]

# Iterate over prefixes forming sequentially numbered filenames
for prefix in prefixes:
   stack = cv2.imread(f'{prefix}_1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   for N in range(2,6):
      # Load image and concatenate onto stack
      im = cv2.imread(f'{prefix}_{N}.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      stack = np.concatenate((stack, im), axis=0)
   # Save concatenated stack
   cv2.imwrite(f'{prefix}_concat.jpg', stack)
```

---

The simplest way is to look for all the `XX_1.jpg` files to get the stem (i.e. prefix) of your filenames. Then construct the 5 numbered versions and make a list and then use Numpy `np.concat()` to stack them atop each other.

Without writing all the code, something like this:

```
import glob, re
import numpy as np

# iterate over all "XX_1.jpg" files
for f in glob.glob('[A-Z][A-Z]_1.jpg'):
    print(f)
    stem = re.split('_', f)[0]
    print(stem)
```

That will produce this list of all your prefixes:

```
DE_1.jpg
DE
BC_1.jpg
BC
AB_1.jpg
AB
```

Comment: Here it is selecting files which have atleast filenames with _5 but I want all images which are till _5 or less than _5....

Comment: My forecast: _Getting error-- ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated_

Comment: @Ani Just `break` out the loop if one of the `cv2.imread()` calls fails.

Comment: @HansHirse  :-)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for img in img_dir:
    for i in nums:
        if str(i) in img:
            img = img.replace('i', 'Concat')
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how the above can concatenate images vertically......

Comment: Please try the above solution on some images by renaming the file names as above and see whether you are getting same output which I asked for in the problem statement......

Comment: @InyoungKim I tried the above after renaming images name I am not getting the solution which I asked for....
Can you please test the same once.....

Answer (score 0):

Either it does, or it doesn't.  Tired, gonna shower.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

path = r'D:\split'
out = r'D:\concat_test'

for root, _, files in os.walk( path ):
    heads = {}
    for file in files:
        head, tail = file.split( '_', 1 )
        version, extension = tail .split( '.', 1 )
        if head not in heads or version > heads [head] ['vers']:
            heads [head] = { 'vers':version, 'ext':extension }

    for h in heads:  ##  AB, BC, CA
        head = heads [h]  ##  local reference
        images = []
        for i in range( head ['vers'] )
            imagename = h +i +head ['ext']
            img = cv2.imread( os.path.join( root, imagename ), 0 )  ##  color, grey, alpha
            images .append( img )

        concat = cv2.vconcat( images )
        concat_name = os.path.join( out,  h +'concat' +head ['ext'] )
        cv2.imwrite( concat_name, concat )
```