# how to display multiple image copies and source image in one tkinter frame

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

i am able to display saved mp4 file in 1 frame and want to try copy the source and display it in one frame with the source mp4.

as following image

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()
root.title("Video!")

# vid = cv2.VideoCapture("vid1.mp4")
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
def get_frame():
    ret,frame = vid.read()
    if ret :
        return(ret,cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    else :
        return(ret,None)
def update():
    ret,frame = get_frame()
    if ret :
        img = Image.fromarray(frame)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = photo, anchor = NW)
        canvas.image=photo
    root.after(delay,update)

canvas = Canvas(root, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()
delay = 15
update()
root.mainloop()
vid.release()
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cv2.vconcat` and `cv2.hconcat` to unite your images and show them at once.

For example if you modify your update function like this:

```
def update():
    ret,frame = get_frame()
    im1 = frame           #your first desired image
    im2 = frame.copy()    #second image
    im3 = frame.copy()    #third image
    im4 = frame.copy()    #fourth image
    im5 = frame.copy()    #fifth image
    im6 = frame.copy()    #last image

    upper_part = cv2.hconcat([im1,im2,im3]) 
    lower_part= cv2.hconcat([im4,im5,im6]) 
    final_image = cv2.vconcat([upper_part,lower_part])

    if ret :
        img = Image.fromarray(final_image) 
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = photo, anchor = NW)
        canvas.image=photo
    root.after(delay,update)
```

You will get the six image concatenated and placed on your tkinter frame. Check here for more info on concatenation in opencv: [Combining Two Images with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589012/combining-two-images-with-opencv)